# Excel Поменять местами слова в ячейке

Tags: excel

Есть файл с колонкой

Имя Фамилия Отчество

Нужно привести к православному ФИО (Фамилия Имя Отчество)

есть

> анониним анониномов анонимович

нужно

> анониномов анониним анонимович

в результате нужен ексель с правильным порядком. можно и в этом столбце менять, можно скопировать результат в свободный столбец, без разницы

можно что-то вроде =ПСТР(A1&", "&A1;ПОИСК("/";ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;",";"/";2))+2;ДЛСТР(A1))

=ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2)+1;300)&" "&ПСТР(A2;1;ПОИСК(" ";A2))

получаю анониномов анонимович анониним

Comment: [статья с примерами](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-c2930414-9678-49d7-89bc-1bf66e219ea8)

Comment: Опиши конкретнее что нужно сделать и что есть сейчас: нужно ли это сделать с помощью встроенных функций? с помощью макроса? в программе на другом языке программирования? должно ли замениться значение ячейки или хватит вывода в соседней колонке?

Comment: чем не устраивает вариант приведенный в вопросе?

Comment: он не работает увы

Comment: стоит добавить как именно он не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> =ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2)+1;ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ПОИСК(" ";A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2)+1);ДЛСТР(A2))-ПОИСК(" ";A2)-1)&" "&ЛЕВСИМВ(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2))&"
>   "&ПСТР(A2;1+НАЙТИ(СИМВОЛ(1);ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;"
>   ";СИМВОЛ(1);ДЛСТР(A2)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;" ";""))));ДЛСТР(A2))

Comment: des1roer, Ваша формула ставит лишний пробел после имени. Мелочь, но разбираться лень.

Comment: Нужно со 125 позиции убрать три символа" "&

Answer (score 1):

Давайте будем проще )

```
=ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПСТР(A1;ПОИСК(" ";A1)+1;50);" ";" "& ЛЕВБ(A1;ПОИСК(" ";A1)))
```

Формула меняет положение первого слова - ставит его после второго

50 - число больше наибольшего количества символов в ФИО. Если найдется ФИО длиннее, смело меняйте 50 на 999 )

Можно заменить на

```
ДЛСТР(A1)-ПОИСК(" ";A1)
```

но особого смысла в этом нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ПСТР(A1;ПОИСК(" ";A1;1)+1;ПОИСК(" ";A1;ПОИСК(" ";A1;1)+1)-ПОИСК(" ";A1)-1)&" "&ПСТР(A1;1;ПОИСК(" ";A1)-1)&" "&ПСТР(A1;ПОИСК(" ";A1;ПОИСК(" ";A1)+1)+1;ДЛСТР(A1)-ПОИСК(" ";A1;ПОИСК(" ";A1)+1))
```